# Viewing CSS Intellisense in partial views and Content pages - Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: css, visual-studio, intellisense, partial-views, content-pages

I am trying to figure out how to get Intellisense for CSS to render when in a partial view or a content page. Of course I don't want it to render a runtime, as the css comes from the masterpage.

I found this trick....

```
<%if (false) {%> <link rel="Stylesheet" href="styles.css"/> <%}%>
```

But is there a better option?

Answer (score 0):

Same idea, but no code nuggets and language independent:

`<link rel="Stylesheet" href="styles.css" runat="server" visible="false" />`